# Wrong explanation about science by Prophet Muhammad

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith, science

This is the hadith:-

> Hadith
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ يَحْيَى، حَدَّثَنَا عَفَّانُ، حَدَّثَنَا
>   حَمَّادٌ، حَدَّثَنَا ثَابِتٌ، عَنْ أَنَسِ بْنِ مَالِكٍ، وَهِشَامُ بْنُ
>   عُرْوَةَ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه
>   وسلم سَمِعَ أَصْوَاتًا ‏.‏ فَقَالَ ‏‏ مَا هَذَا الصَّوْتُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>   قَالُوا النَّخْلُ يُؤَبِّرُونَهُ فَقَالَ ‏"‏ لَوْ لَمْ يَفْعَلُوا
>   لَصَلَحَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ فَلَمْ يُؤَبِّرُوا عَامَئِذٍ فَصَارَ شِيصًا
>   فَذَكَرُوا لِلنَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَقَالَ ‏"‏ إِنْ كَانَ
>   شَيْئًا مِنْ أَمْرِ دُنْيَاكُمْ فَشَأْنَكُمْ بِهِ وَإِنْ كَانَ شَيْئًا
>   مِنْ أُمُورِ دِينِكُمْ فَإِلَىَّ ‏"‏ ‏.‏"
>
> It was narrated from 'Aisha that the Prophet (ﷺ) heard some sounds and
>   said:
>
> "What is this noise?" They said: "Palm trees that are being
>   pollinated." He said: "If they did not do that it would be better." So
>   they did not pollinate them that year, and the dates did not mature
>   properly. they mentioned that to the Prophet (ﷺ) and he said: "If it
>   is one of the matters of your religion, then refer to me."
>
> Sahih (Darussalam)
>
> English : Vol. 3, Book 16, Hadith 2471  Arabic : Book 16, Hadith 2565

Okay now, why did Rasulullah (sm) tell them to not pollinate the plants?

If he didn't know about matters outside the sphere of religion, why did he comment about it in the first place?

I got the hadith from [this](https://youtu.be/E2IFxopDnMw) video.

If there's any problem in my question please inform me. Thanks!

Comment: What is the relevance to science here?

Comment: Does this imply palm trees are manually pollinated, as in, by humans? Asking because of the "they did not pollinate them that year." Also, what is the noise of palm trees being pollinated? It appears as though palm trees, like many trees, are [wind-pollinated](https://www.hunker.com/12170377/how-do-palm-trees-reproduce). (Perhaps this should be a separate question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, where is the "wrong explanation about science"? You are assuming that the Prophet said that no pollination at all is better, however the Prophet is only talking about human assisted pollination.

Dates are also pollinated naturally by wind and insects. Its effectiveness depends on different factors, including climate (flow of wind), proportion and placement of male trees to female trees etc.

In some cases the wind and proportion of male trees is such that natural dispersion is adequate to pollinate all female trees which then bear fruit, manual pollination does not bring any improvement above what nature is already doing.

However in some case, the wind-flow is poor or male trees are extremely few in proportion to females, so without manual pollination many of the female trees remain unpollinated, causing a very poor yield. In this case manual pollination can cause a great improvement in yield, especially since most of the trees are fruit-bearing females.

Next, these Hadith are from [Sahih Muslim](https://ia802500.us.archive.org/6/items/SahihMuslimEngVolume6_201404/119788073-Sahih-Muslim-Vol-6.pdf):

[image]

[image]

The Prophet did not imply that he was sure of it, he expressed his *thought* أَظُنُّ  and showed uncertainty with *perhaps* لَعَلَّكُمْ. He was making a hypothesis and left room for it to be incorrect. His opinion may have been based on past observation of date palms that produced fruit without requiring manual pollination, as he was a migrant from Mecca.

Thirdly, the Prophet is a human being, he only knows of the unseen what Allah has taught him, and Allah has not sent revelation about every matter and left many worldly affairs to discovery and consultation, if you read seerah you can see many examples of him consulting with his companions and at times taking their opinions against his own, e.g where to fight in Uhud and how to defend in Ahzab and whether to agree on a tribute etc.